# How do I make a function called isNumber that receives a parameter called val and returns a boolean indicating whether the parameter is of type number

Tags: javascript

Some examples I received:

```
1 => true
0 => true
true => false
null => false
'1' => false
```

Comment: what a programming language are you writing in ? because if you are in javascript, you can use `Number.isNaN` infact or programming languages have this by default

Comment: I'm using a JavaScript language

Comment: But how would the type of be in the code?

Comment: @AnonimousDev123 what about `NaN` and `Infinity`? Technically these are numbers too.

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude `Number.isNaN('1')` is `false`, since it parses strings automatically.

Comment: Use the `typeof` operator, it will return `number` for numbers.

Comment: I just need to create this function and make it return a boolean indicating whether the parameter is of type number

Comment: okay let me post an answer for you

Comment: @Barmar not exactly. `isNaN()` parses the strings and returns true if they are `NaN`. `Number.isNaN()` returns true when you explicitely pass `NaN`. So `Number.isNaN(1)` also returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the comments, use typeof against `number` and `bigint`

```js
function isNumber(val) {
  return typeof val === 'number' || typeof val === 'bigint';
}

// test
console.log(isNumber(1)) // => true
console.log(isNumber(0)) // => true
console.log(isNumber(true)) // => false
console.log(isNumber(null)) // => false
console.log(isNumber('1')) // => false
```

Comment: Does not fully solve : `isNumber(Infinity); // true`

Comment: @JérémieRPK unclear, because OP didn't answer yet what about NaN and Infinity; let alone BitInt.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite

```
Number.isFinite(1); // true
Number.isFinite(-0.1); // true
Number.isFinite(null); // false
Number.isFinite('x'); // false
Number.isFinite('1'); // false
Number.isFinite(Infinity); // false
Number.isFinite(NaN); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isNumber(val) {
  return /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(val);
}
```

Comment: Wow regulat expressions is lucrative, but it will pass for '1' which is not what @AnonimousDev123 wants

Comment: He can combine with checking type of val. Type in ['number','bigint']